# Using CSS or other instead of js to display decimal as superscript

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of:

```
<span class="price">17.998,80</span>
```

Customer wants me to replace with:

```
<span class="price">17.998<sup>80</sup></span>
```

...fine, lets javascript... BUT WAIT!

Could the equivalent result not be obtained via some fancy CSS/CSS trick?

(large $ figures, no decimal, superscript cents - , is my decimal delimiter)

Kind Regards,

Steen

NOTE: This works fine:

```
$('span.price').html($('span.price').html().replace(',','<sup>')+'</sup>');
```

BUT preference is to ALL CSS/CSS3 solution

Comment: I don't understand. The `<sup>` tag will create the superscript. What are you after if not that?

Comment: He don't want to use any other element to achieve that kind of appearance.. I don't think you can do it just with css.. you have to use at least javascript or to change the code which displays your prices

Comment: open notepad++ and replace all `,` with `<sup>` and `</span>` with `</sup></span>` . I think you can do this ?

Comment: Well - I get the price info via ajax and lod that in . Would just have liked to avoid any js at all for performance and milliseconds where user sees original....

Comment: It's interesting that you care about performance when it comes to adding trivial formatting markup, but it looks like you are using jQuery (which is considerably slower than using native JS functionality).

Comment: @cimmanon  - Touché.... :-) That one must be reworked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to find all your price and add the HTML `<sup> ... </sup>` because if someone do not load javascript there is no **HTML markup**.

And there is no **CSS** trick to to that.

The only thing that **CSS** do is to apply a style to the `<sup>` element.

Comment: Sometime no is the right answer :-). Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no CSS trick for the purpose: you cannot refer to digits after decimal point in content without turning them into an element.

A `sup` element is not really adequate for the purpose, since it puts characters in a superscript position so that they look like an exponent. A better approach is to generate

```
<span class="price">17.998<span class="cents">80</span></span>
```

and style it with

```
 .cents {
   font-size: 0.7em;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 0.25em;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are stuck with Javascript unless you can get the service you are calling with AJAX to return each price in two elements: Euros and cents:

```
<span class="priceEuros">17.998</span>,<span class="priceCents">80</span>
```

Of course, if they are separate elements, they would be easy to style separately.

Answer (score 0):

## CSS Superscript and Subscript:

```
.super{
  vertical-align: super;
 }
.sub{
  vertical-align: sub;
 }
```

<sub>([Source](https://cssnewbie.com/create-superscript-and-subscript-text-in-css/))</sub>